# How can I get Dto name for the database table?

Tags: hibernate

I am new to this hibernate , I  need to change table name in query dynamically,which comes from some configuration file(class), so in hibernate we cant query on table names directly I need respective dto  name for tables , How can I get Dto name for the database table?

Comment: have a look at this maybe it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239450/clone-a-tables-definition-with-hibernate-hbm2ddl/1240489#1240489